# i want to show my error message from controller to html thymleaf spring boots

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, spring

```
if(checkcode.isPresent()){          
            redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("errorMessage", "This products have already !");
            return "redirect:/save-product";
            
        } else if (checkname.isPresent()) {
            
            redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("errorMessage", "This product have already !");
            return "redirect:/save-product";
}
```

```
<div th:if="${errorMessage}">
    <div th:text="${errorMessage}"></div>
</div>
```

This is my Controller and my div show error message to thymleaf but this one can't show on my thymleaf page

Answer (score 0):

addFlashAttribute() Modify to addAttribute()